# How do I parse a json file using gson?

Tags: java, json, parsing, utf-8, gson

i'm trying to read certain lines from a large json file using gson. the problem is that the code that i wrote won't parse the utf-8 encoding.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
    Items[] myItems = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("./input/raw-1.json"), Items[].class);
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(myItems));

Gson gson2 = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("./output/output-sample-test.json"));
    gson2.toJson(myItems, writer);
    writer.close();

class Items {
    long id;
    int dayId;
    String clientAddress;
    String pickupAddress;
    String venueName;
    String pickupTime;
    double pickupLat;
    double pickupLon;
    double deliveryLat;
    double deliveryLon;
}
```

it will output these weird signs:

```
"clientAddress": "Timisoara, Strada Gheorghe LazÃ„Æ’r nr. 24, bloc Fructus Plaza, ap. 22, et. 7"
```

what am i doing wrong ? by the way, sorry for my bad english. thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is supposed to be encoded in UTF-8. `FileReader` assumes the file is encoded in the default encoding for text files for your system which might not be UTF-8. If you use `Files.newBufferedReader` you can speicify the encoding:

```
try (Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("./input/raw-1.json"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
    Items[] myItems = gson.fromJson(reader, Items[].class);
}
```

Likewise, you should specify the encoding when writing:

```
try (Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("./output/output-sample-test.json", StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
    gson2.toJson(myItems, writer);
}
```

Comment: yep, it's working now, perfect. thank you very much !!